# Unable to parse date type field in Kibana

Tags: date, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

**I am new to elastic search and kibana**. 
I want to parse a _source field as `date` type in following format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", but with no luck. However, if the value of field is in "yyyy-mm-hh" format, then the field gets parsed as a date type. 
I tried modifying `dateFormat:scaled` field in kibana's advanced settings page, but with no luck.
Following is my use case:

```
{
    "name": "Amy",
    "time_of_creation": "2016-12-21 10:46:55"
}
```

In my case `"time_of_creation"` field is getting parsed as a `String` in kibana, I want to parse this field as `"date"` type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing format is wrong. You are using this:

"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Note that you are using the same letters "mm" for both the months and the minutes. For months you have to use capital "M". Also, bear in mind that if you specify the hours with "hh", you are parsing a 12-hour format. If you need a 24-hour format, use "HH" instead. For instance, this mapping will correctly parse dates with a 24-hour format:

```
"time_of_creation": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
}
```

You can check [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/mapping-date-format.html) on this topic for details.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet , so I am posting to ask for more information and then edit the answer.

Can you post your mapping and one sample document?

In case that you don't know , this is how you get the mapping :

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping"
```

You can get one sample document with .

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search"
```

Comment: mapping for "default" document. 
{
  "default": {
    "mappings": {
      "vox-log": {
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "date_time": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: sample document:  {
  "took": 74,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "default",
        "_type": "vox-log",
        "_id": "AVksHIL52Bkrx4u9vIi9",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "data": "\nkjhjkhkj\njjkhjkhjk\njhkjhjk",
          "date_time": "2016-12-21 10:46:50.119"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by lacking of the timezone infomation of ur time format.
And u can checkout the relevant solution on [the official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/date.html).
Time with time zone information should look like this:

```
    2016-11-11T11:11:11.111+0800
```

Example codes:

```
PUT my_index {
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date" 
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}

PUT my_index/my_type/1 { "date": "2015-01-01" } 

PUT my_index/my_type/2 { "date": "2015-01-01T12:10:30Z" } 

PUT my_index/my_type/3 { "date": 1420070400001 } 

GET my_index/_search {   
    "sort": { "date": "asc"}
}
```

:)

Comment: can u share the url of official guide?

Comment: @OnkaarSingh here it is [the guides of the time format data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/date.html), and I have added to my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the date in wrong format. Kibana needs to have the timezone of the date as well. So I converted my date string using following code and then sent data in elasticsearch. It is now reading the field as `date` type now.

```
var date = new Date("2016-12-21 10:46:50.119");
var dateStr = date.toISOString()
```

dateStr is now `2016-12-21T05:16:50.119Z` which is the required format.